# libusb_claim_interface raises SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) in Win7 64bit

Tags: c, libusb-1.0

I am trying to work with USB HID Composite device (Self-written). 
There are two interfaces, both HID. But second one is Custom HID.

I am using libusb-1.0, but that's is that I can it is open device. Any other operations I tried raises SEGV.

This is the code (QT Creator, MinGW64):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int i=0;
struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
libusb_device ** devs;
libusb_device * dev;

int r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;
int cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
if (cnt < 0)
    return cnt;

while((dev = devs[i++]) != 0){
    r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
        return -1;
    }

    if (desc.idVendor == 0x0483){
        libusb_device_handle * h;
        if (!libusb_open(dev,&h)){
                if (0 == (r=libusb_claim_interface (h,1)) )
```

Here I got SIGSEGV.
I tried to get string descriptor and set configuration as well. I've got same result.

Where I wrong?

Comment: `if (cnt < 0)` -->> `if (cnt <= 0)` seems more logical.

Comment: cnt == 0 - it's a kind of non-error case. Zero devices found. This means than next loop has 0 iterations.
Negative result means error. 
Bottom line: I disagree. 
Also this completely non-relevant to question: I found the device. This means that cnt>0